# php post request with --data

Tags: php, post, riak

I try to make a request from my php code to another remote server which has Riak DB running. I need to make a map-reduce request so I have to do it with POST http.

Riak documentation says (for e.g.)

```
curl -XPOST http://`localhost`:8091/mapred \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
"inputs":"training",
"query":[{"map":{"language":"javascript",
"source":"function(riakObject) {
var m = riakObject.values[0].data.match(/pizza/g);
return [[riakObject.key, (m ? m.length : 0 )]];
}"}}]}'
```

How to do the same with PHP?

Comment: php does have a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

You can use the PHP cUrl library for this. Be sure to enable it in the PHP modules.

Edit:

the --data flag tells cUrl to use POST, this is the PHP variant

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $body)
```

Where the body variable can be the data, for example JSon.

Comment: But what that -d (or --data) goes for in PHP curl ?

Comment: Edited;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762843/php-curl-with-data-flag << that code in the post is kinda correct.