# Need help to convert cURL Command Line to run from PHP file

Tags: php, curl

The cURL command that I run from the command line is:

```
curl --digest -u "username:password" "http://[ip-address]:8086/streammanager/streamAction?action=resetStream" --data "vhostName=_defaultVHost_&appName=rtr_planeta/_definst_&streamName=rtr_planeta.stream"
```

The problem I am facing is with the following part of the command:

```
 --data "vhostName=_defaultVHost_&appName=rtr_planeta/_definst_&streamName=rtr_planeta.stream"
```

**Where in PHP code do I specify** `--data`?

I got this far:

```
<?php
$url="http://[ip-address]:8086/streammanager/streamAction?action=resetStream";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{    
  echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762843/php-curl-with-data-flag

Comment: I think you are searching for it :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865817/how-to-convert-curl-file-post-from-command-line-into-php-curl

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207236/curl-command-line-to-php-curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$param = 'vhostName=_defaultVHost_&appName=rtr_planeta/_definst_&streamName=rtr_planeta.stream';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
```